# Create a LinkedIn share button

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

How can I create a LinkedIn share button through which I can share something to a particular person? Also I want to create a LinkedIn login button through which it will open a popup and ask for LinkedIn credentials and on successful login it will close.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, the [Original Linkedin Developer Share Documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share) is just a blank page, and now, since they have been acquired by Microsoft, you can find a newer one here: [Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin).

The new documentation doesn't mention any other field but: `url`.  So, if you want to share, it's as simple as...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

If you are interested in a regularly maintained github project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]

Answer (score 0):

Try LinkedIn Developer site for the share button: [LinkedIn Share Plugin Generator](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share#!)

Take a look at this link to find more about Sign in with Linked In: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin